# how to hide div using radio_button_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 radio buttons and 3 divs like:

```
<%= radio_button_tag('radioButton','1')%>
<%= radio_button_tag('radioButton','2')%>
<%= radio_button_tag('radioButton','3')%>

<div id="div1"  style="display: none;">div1</div>
<div id="div2"  style="display: none;">div2</div>
<div id="div3"  style="display: none;">div3</div>
```

I am new in rails.I want to show `div1` when first radibutton is clicked,show `div2` when second radibutton is clicked and show `div3` when third radibutton is clicked.

I can easily do it in ASP.NET but how i can do it in ROR. Can i achieve this without using JavaScript or ajax.

Comment: This screams for JavaScript though ..

Comment: I don't know much about JavaScript that's why i want to do it in Rails, is it possible or i bound to use Javascript.

Comment: Anytime you have "live" front-end interaction, it means you need JavaScript one way or another

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

Make js file with following code:

```
$(function() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('radioButton');
    var delivery_div = document.getElementById('div1');
    var showHiddenDiv = function(){
        if(checkbox.checked) {
            delivery_div.style['display'] = 'block';
        } else {
            delivery_div.style['display'] = 'none';
        }
    }
    checkbox.onclick = showHiddenDiv;
    showHiddenDiv();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the other divs when a radio is clicked you can try this:

Your view template does not change anything:

```
<%= radio_button_tag('radioButton','1') %>
<%= radio_button_tag('radioButton','2') %>
<%= radio_button_tag('radioButton','3') %>

<div id="div1" style="display: none;">div1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none;">div2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display: none;">div3</div>
```

In your javascript file, let's say `application.js` (note that if you include in that one, all the radio buttons will have this behaviour... You can use a class and bind that class only)

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click","input[type=radio]", function() {
    var id = "#div"+$(this).val();
    $(id).show(); // display associated div
    $("div[id^='div']:not(" + id + ")").hide() // hide the others
  })
});
```